# Python simple not in statement not working

Tags: python, list, if-statement

In python I am trying to run this code:

```
    blacklist = ['hello', 'man']
    for word in open("text.txt"):
      if word not in blacklist:
          print(word)
```

In text.txt I have

```
test hello man
```

I would like the output to be:

```
test
```

But - it just returns the text of text.txt!
What is the issue?

Comment: Try `print`ing the `word` right after the `for` line and you will see your issue.

Comment: iterating over a file returns lines, not words.

Comment: You should use `split()`, like `word.split()` then you will get a list `['test', 'hello', 'man']`

Comment: for line in open('test.txt'): words = line.split(' ')